# How to get access to object in class?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following class structure:

```
export class LayerEditor {
    public layerManager: LayerManager;
    public commandManager: CommandManager;
    public tools: EditorTools;

    constructor() {
       this.commandManager = new CommandManager();
       this.layerManager = new LayerManager(reonMap);
    }
}


class LayerManager {
      constructor() {}

      selectLayer() {
          // TODO
      }
}
```

As you see above there is a editor class with layerManager inside. How to get access to `this.commandManager` inside `LayerManager.selectLayer()`?

Comment: Any reason why `LayerManager` can't just be passed a `commandManager` in its constructor?

Comment: There is not, I can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//CommandManager.ts
export class CommandManager {
    name : string;

    constructor() {
       this.name =" I am a CommandManager";
    }
}
```

Import `CommandManagaer`:

```
import { CommandManager } from "./CommandManager";

export class LayerEditor {
    public layerManager: LayerManager;
    public commandManager: CommandManager;

    constructor() {
       this.commandManager = new CommandManager();
    }
}


export class LayerManager {
      constructor(private layerEditor : LayerEditor) {}

      selectLayer() {
         console.log(this.layerEditor.commandManager.name)
      }
    }
```

Try:

```
 const le = new LayerEditor();
 const lm = new LayerManager(le);
 lm.selectLayer();
```

This will print `I am the manager`

Comment: Or just pass `this`

Comment: Better to pass just what `LayerManager` will _need_ (in this case `CommandManager`), rather than passing in a much larger object graph